# Granularity in time function

Tags: c, posix

Is there any way to check the granularity of gettimeofday()  function provided by POSIX?

Comment: I'm unclear about your question: per standard the resolution is in microseconds - "The gettimeofday() function shall obtain the current time, expressed as seconds and microseconds since the Epoch"

Are you asking whether there's a programmatic way of checking that the resolution of the system clock is less than a microsecond?

Comment: @RomanK: Resolution and granularity aren't the same thing.  POSIX indeed specifies microseconds, but on a given implementation those microseconds might only increment by, for example, 1000 at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call it in a tight loop, note the difference between the current value and the previous one when it changes. Something like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

int main()
{
        struct timeval timevals[2];
        int cur = 0;
        while (1) {
                gettimeofday(&timevals[cur], NULL);
                int diff = timevals[cur].tv_usec - timevals[!cur].tv_usec;
                if (diff)
                        printf("%d\n", diff);
                cur = !cur;
        }
}
```

On my system it seems the granularity is around 2 usec (about 50/50 one or two microseconds, with outliers in the hundreds or thousands that are likely due to task switching).

Comment: You are over-estimating the delay because you are counting the time taken to format the difference too.  You should call `gettimeofday(&timevals[!cur], NULL);` immediately after the `cur = !cur;` line so that the gap between calls is minimized.  You will likely find that the result is most often zero - because your machine is fast enough to make two `gettimeofday()` calls in a single microsecond.  Don't forget, a microsecond is 3000 clock cycles if your CPU runs at 3 GHz; you can do quite a lot in 3000 clock cycles.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `gettimeofday()`, consider using `clock_gettime()` (specifying the `CLOCK_REALTIME` clock).  This is also POSIX, and supports a [`clock_getres()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/clock_getres.html) function to obtain the resolution.

Comment: But `clock_getres` always return 1 ns for hrtimers instead of real timer resolution....

Answer (score -1):

The current posix way to get the resolution of gettimeofday() is

```
#include <unistd.h>
long ticks_per_sec = sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK);
```

In older posix versions (not sure when the change happened), the value CLOCKS_PER_SEC was #defined.

Comment: CLOCKS_PER_SEC is Standard C and applies to `clock()`; `_SC_CLK_TCK` applies to `times()`.  Neither applies to `gettimeofday()`.