# What is the unit of gettimeofday()?

Tags: c++, c, gettimeofday

I've a program to calculate the latency of an object in a pub-sub model. I've used the following function for timestamp:

```
uint64_t GetTimeStamp() {
    struct timeval tv;
    gettimeofday(&tv,NULL);
    return tv.tv_sec*(uint64_t)1000000+tv.tv_usec;
}
```

The latency is measured as timestamp difference in publisher and subscriber. So, I'm concerned about the unit of the latency measured. Is it in seconds or microseconds??

Comment: `man gettimeofday` to see struct timeval details

Comment: Just simply look with what constant you are multiplying seconds to get something else. 1sec = 1000000 microseconds.

Comment: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/sys/time.h.html :)

Comment: Strictly speaking, that's the unit of _reporting_, not measurement.

Comment: If you have C++11 (gcc 4.7.2+), look at [std::chrono](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) (cppreference has a good example), for an example usage with milliseconds: http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/code/445750/simple-timer-using-c11s-chrono-library. One of the nice things about std::chrono is a quick search and replace on "milliseconds" -> "microseconds" or "nanoseconds" and you have that resolution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `timeval` structure has `tv_sec`, which gives you the absolute value for the seconds, and `tv_usec`, which gives you the *remaining* fraction in micro seconds.

So, you could get the resolution in micro seconds.

For more information, http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Elapsed-Time.html

Answer (score 4):

tv.tv_sec gives the second count, tv.tv_usec gives the remaining microsecond count.

For gettimeofday() principle and its accuracy:

[How is the microsecond time of linux gettimeofday() obtained and what is its accuracy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13230719/how-is-the-microsecond-time-of-linux-gettimeofday-obtained-and-what-is-its-acc)

[Is gettimeofday() guaranteed to be of microsecond resolution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/88/is-gettimeofday-guaranteed-to-be-of-microsecond-resolution)