# How clock_gettime achieves nano seconds resolution?

Tags: linux, timer, resolution, clock

Which system hardware **timer** does `clock_gettime` function in linux use internally to give **nano seconds level resolution** back to the user code when invoked to measure elapsed time for a given segment of code ?

Comment: You should have a look at the manpage of [`clock_gettime`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime).

Comment: [How is the microsecond time of linux gettimeofday() obtained and what is its accuracy?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13230719/1504523) may shed some light on the scheme.

Comment: IIRC, Linux cannot give ns resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modern CPUs run at several GHz clock frequency. A frequency of 1 GHz equals a clock period of 1 ns. So running a (wide) counter at 1 GHz gives a time resolution in nanoseconds. This does not mean that the time is as accurate as it is displayed. The value has just such a high resolution.