# Disabling OpenMP pragma statements everywhere in my c++ project

Tags: c++, macros, openmp, pragma

In my c++ project, there are several `#pragma omp parallel for private(i)` statements. When I try to track down bugs in my code using valgrind, the OpenMP adornments result in "possibly lost" memory leak messages.  I would like to totally disable all of the aforementioned `#pragma` statements so that I can isolate the problem.

However, I use `omp_get_wtime()` in my code, and I do not wish to disable these function calls.  So I don't want to totally disable all OpenMP functionality in my project.

How can I simply turn off all the `#pragma omp parallel for private(i)` statements?

I use Eclipse CDT to automatically manage makefiles, and so I normally compile in release mode by: `make all -C release`.  Ideally, I would like a solution to my problem that permits me to compile using a statement such as `make all -C release -TURN_OFF_PARALLEL` which would result in all the aforementioned `#pragma` statements being turned off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is to:

1. disable OpenMP
2. link the OpenMP stub library functions

In case your OpenMP implementation doesn't provide stub functions, you can create your own copying from Appendix B of the [standard](http://www.openmp.org/mp-documents/OpenMP3.1.pdf).

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "link the OpenMP stub library functions"?

Comment: The idea is to link a _serial library_ with the API defined in `omp.h`. Some compilers provide a flag to do that, so the only thing you need is just to change a flag at compile time. This, for instance, is a [reference for Intel](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/studio/composer/en-us/2011Update/compiler_c/copts/common_options/option_openmp_stubs.htm)

Comment: What is your opinion on using the `boost::timer` [class](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/timer/doc/cpu_timers.html) instead of the OpenMP `omp_get_wtime()` function?  Because I'm not using any other OpenMP functions.

Comment: I don't see any issue with that

Comment: @Massimiliano, How do you link only the stub function in GCC?  In Visual Studio it's not a problem as omp_get_wtime works without setting OpenMP support.  In ICC you can use -openmp-stubs.  I don't see an option for GCC.

Comment: Appendix B says "double omp_get_wtime(void)
{
/* This function does not provide a working
* wallclock timer. Replace it with a version
* customized for the target machine.
*/
return 0.0;
}".  That's not a good solution if you need the function.

Comment: @raxman I don't think GCC provides a stub implementation. As for the timing functions, obviously they depend on the machine. What the standard prescribes is the API to which you have to conform.

Answer (score 2):

Following some dwelling around [an interesting question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33160934/5239503) about a non-working OpenMP code, it turns out that it is perfectly possible to get the equivalent of a stub OpenMP lib with GCC by only replacing the `-fopenmp` with `-lgomp`. I doubt it was a intended feature, but it works out of the box nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

For GCC I don't see an option to use only the stubs.  Appendix B of the OpenMP standard says

```
    double omp_get_wtime(void)
    {
    /* This function does not provide a working
    * wallclock timer. Replace it with a version
    * customized for the target machine.
    */
    return 0.0;
    }
```

That's useless if you actually want the time.  With GCC, either you have to write your own time function or you search for "#pragma omp" and replace it with "//#pragma omp"

Rather than changing the whole code base you could implement your own time function for GCC only.
[Computing time in linux :granularity and precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16740014/computing-time-in-linux-granularity-and-precision?noredirect=1#comment24196371_16740014)

Comment: See it this way: implementing the stub `omp_get_wtime()` you modify an external substitute library in one single place. Your advice is to modify potentially all the codebase of a project.

Comment: Yes, I understand, but writing your own accurate cross platform timing function can be a pain, that's the whole point in using omp_get_wtime().