# c operation takes 0 seconds

Tags: c, time

I am trying to measure how much time takes serial program to reverse an array. My code:

```
#include <time.h>

int main() {
   int n = 100000;
   int c, d, a[n], b[n];
   clock_t start, end;

   for (c = 0; c < n ; c++)
      a[c] = c;

   start = clock();

   for (c = n - 1, d = 0; c >= 0; c--, d++)
      b[d] = a[c];

   end = clock();
   printf("Number of seconds: %f\n", (end-start)/(double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC );

   return 0;
}
```

However, it is always takes 0.000000 seconds to run. Why? If I increase `n`, I get segmentation errors.

Comment: You should be aware that this does not reverse your array as you reverse twice! Think about (for example) the first iteration which reverse c=n-1, d=0 and the last iteration which reverse c=0, d=n-1...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try many iterations:

```
#include <time.h>

int main() {
int n = 100000;
int c, d, a[n], b[n];
clock_t start, end;
start = clock();
for(int i =0; i< 100000000;i++) {
  for (c = 0; c < n ; c++)
   a[c] = c;
for (c = n - 1, d = 0; c >= 0; c--, d++)
  b[d] = a[c];
}
end = clock();
printf("Number of seconds: %f\n", (end-start)/(double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC/100000000 );
return 0;
}
```

but better read this: [C++ clock stays zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18696505/c-clock-stays-zero)

Answer (score 3):

The loop:

```
   for (c = n - 1, d = 0; c >= 0; c--, d++)
      b[d] = a[c];
```

is optimized out by your compiler. Your compiler figured out `b` and `a` are not  further used in your program.

To avoid the compiler optimizing out the loop you can pass `b` and `a` as arguments to a dummy external function. You could also use `volatile` qualifiers but this is likely to bias your result.

Comment: So, how can I fix it?

Comment: You could print a random element of the arrays near end of program.

Comment: @ouha wouldn't `-O0` on GCC remedy that?

Comment: @Qix could or couldn't be as even with `-O0` `gcc` performs some optimizations. But the point is if you want to measure performances, you don't want to compile a program with `-O0`.

Comment: I added printing a random element near the end of a program - did not help.

Comment: @Bob as maxpovver mentioned in his answer, your loop with only 100000 iterations is also too fast for `clock` to mesure it, you need to repeat the loop.