# openmp code not running in parallel

Tags: openmp

```
omp_set_num_threads( 8 );
#pragma omp parallel for
for( int tx = 0; tx < numThread; tx++ )
{
    cout<<"\nThread :"<<omp_get_num_threads()<<"\n";

}
```

My understanding is that the above code is supposed to print 8. But the output I am getting is

```
Thread :1

Thread :1

Thread :1

Thread :1

Thread :1

Thread :1

Thread :1

Thread :1
```

Please let me know what is going wrong here. I am beginner to openmp and so I am quite sure i must have made some stupid mistake.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What compiler exactly?

Comment: gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) 4.8.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what's happening here.

It can be the case that you compiled with a stub OpenMP library, which provides all the OpenMP library API, but only acting as if sequential mode (see [this link](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/522966) for example for the corresponding Intel compiler switch).

Another possibility is that the `OMP_THREAD_LIMIT` environment variable is set to `1` in your environment. See for example this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>

int main() {
    omp_set_num_threads(8);
    #pragma omp parallel
    #pragma omp single
    std::cout << "Number of threads in the current parallel region is " << omp_get_num_threads() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

When compiled with OpenMP support and run, it gives me:

```
$ g++ -fopenmp nbthreads.cc -o nbthreads
$ ./nbthreads 
Number of threads in the current parallel region is 8
$ OMP_THREAD_LIMIT=1 ./nbthreads 
Number of threads in the current parallel region is 1
```

Aside from these two possibilities, I've no idea.

---

Edit: thanks to [Z boson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33160934/openmp-code-not-running-in-parallel/33166516#comment54144969_33166516)'s
comment, I'm pretty sure I've got the key of the mystery.

With the very same code as the hereabove one, here is what I've got:

```
$ g++ -o nbthreads nbthreads.cc -lgomp
$ ./nbthreads 
Number of threads in the current parallel region is 1
```

So you simply mistakenly used `-lgomp` instead of `-fopenmp` while compiling / linking your code. This gives you an OpenMP code equivalent to having only 1 thread, even if you explicitly ask for more.

Comment: He says he's using GCC. There is no way, unfortunately, to only use the stub functions with GCC: it's all or nothing.  You can do this with ICC and MSVC not not GCC.

Comment: That's interesting. Maybe I'm wrong then? If you only link with `-lgomp` you get the stubs only?  Or at least you get no threads?

Comment: @Zboson I suspect you simply resolve the OpenMP runtime library functions, but since you don't have any `parallel` region, they all give you a sequential answer. This is actually very similar to a stub.

Comment: Probably one should look at the assembly still just to make sure.  Actually I think one could check the binaries with and without the `pragma omp`.  If the binaries are the same then it means it's only using the stub function.

Comment: I just checked. They are the same. So I am wrong. I am happy to be wrong. But that means there are few answers on SO that need to be corrected. Thanks for showing me this!!!

Comment: [This answer is wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17104343/2542702). Go ahead and give a correct answer. You earned it.

Comment: I used changed to -fooenmp and it solved my issue. Thanks a lot

Comment: I should have thought of this. Using `-Wall` with `-lgomp` but without `-fopenmp` shows that the omp pragmas are ignored. So you get the stub functions only.